# Any tips to achieve replication of paper form in vb form and then print and save

Tags: vb6

I'm looking for a tips that I can use to make the following as easy and/or re-usable as possible.
I need to recreate a paper based form in vb6, allow the user to fill in values and then be able to both print out and save the completed form.
I'm thinking of scaning the form and saving it as a jpeg. 
Using this jpg as the picture in a picture box.
Overlaying it with checkboxes/textboxes etc. 
Saving the values of the various controls to the database 
etc.

It seems like a lot of work for just 1 form and not very re-usable.

is there a better way?

Comment: That's pretty much it if you don't want to lay it out manually.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if what you want is "easy" - there isn't any tool which will do everything you want automatically. There are tools to turn paper forms into PDFs - but you would still have to do the database work yourself.

As for "re-usable" - I suppose creating a simple web application will fulfill this criteria, because your users wouldn't have to install your application.